# c# Excel interop name a custom cells range

Tags: c#, excel, interop

If you have Excel you can press Control and for example select cells C4 A22 and B5,  name them for example PLUTO , than you can make calculations on those cells and other things.

NOW !! How can it be done in C# via Excel Interop ?? Im playng about 3 days with getRange but cannot get a result

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
//Select a range of cells

Excel.Range range = (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1:B4", Type.Missing);

//Add Name to Range

range.Name = "Test_Range";
```

Here is more information on [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Mmmm not good because I whant to select DISTINCT cells with the same name ;

Comment: You may want to clarify your question as what you have written does not indicate that clearly.

Comment: example  excel.get_Range("A1,B4,B7,C8", Type.Missing);  not working
and also  excel.get_Range("A1:B4:B7", Type.Missing);
 selects a square area and not the distinct cells. I need to have A1 , B4 and B7 named as you can do by pressing (ctrl + cells) in excel. Is it possible ?

Comment: all this serves to me because i have to do:
=SUM(A6,B6,C7,C9,etc,etc ... till 160 cells) but excel has a limitation in SUM formula, so naming all cells with the same name can grant me the possibility to have =SUM(REPAIR_COSTS) in a single line

Comment: The example I gave gives you the ability to apply the name as you say you want to do. You can then select this range by name in your formula. Either that or apply the name to the cells individually. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I appreciate your help but nothing halps me to select and name circa 160 cells with the same name